# CakePHP 3.x DB mapping, BelongsToMany vs HasMany+HasOne

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.x

I have three tables in DB: (1) *offers*, (2) *offer_rows*, (3) *products*.

*offer_rows* will always point to a *offer*, and possibly (but not always) to a *product*. *offer_rows* has also other fields such as price etc.

Same with (My)SQL:

```
create table offers(
    id serial not null auto_increment primary key,
    ...
);
create table offer_rows(
    id serial not null auto_increment primary key,

    product_id bigint(20) unsigned references products(id),
    offer_id bigint(20) unsigned not null references offers(id),

    price decimal(15,2),
    ...
);
create table products(
    id serial not null auto_increment primary key,
    ...
);
```

In terms of CakePHP (3.3.16), **with the optional reference to a product**, what is the correct mapping?

If the *offer_rows* had a not null restriction to product reference (which it currently does not have), it would seem that a **BelongsToMany** should be used:

```
(class OffersTable)
@property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany $Products

// initialize
$this->belongsToMany('Products', [
     'through' => 'OfferRows',
     'foreignKey' => 'offer_id',
     'joinType' => 'INNER',
     'joinTable' => 'offer_rows',
]);


(class OfferRowsTable)
@property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Products
@property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Offers

// initialize
$this->belongsTo('Products', [
     'foreignKey' => 'product_id'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Offers', [
     'foreignKey' => 'offer_id',
     'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);


(class ProductsTable)
@property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany $Offers

// initialize
$this->belongsToMany('Offers', [
     'through' => 'OfferRows',
     'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
     'joinType' => 'INNER',
     'joinTable' => 'offer_rows',
]);
```

However, with the possibility of the null product, should I use HasMany + HasOne instead?

```
(class OffersTable)
@property \Cake\ORM\Association\HasMany $OfferRows

// initialize
$this->hasMany('OfferRows', [
    'foreignKey' => 'offer_id'
]);

(class OfferRowsTable)
@property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsTo $Offers
@property \Cake\ORM\Association\HasOne $Products

// initialize
$this->belongsTo('Offers', [
       'foreignKey' => 'offer_id',
       'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);        
$this->hasOne('Products', [
    'className' => 'Products',
        'propertyName' => 'reference_product_obj',
        'foreignKey' => 'reference_product'             
]);

(class ProductsTable)
@property \Cake\ORM\Association\BelongsToMany $OfferRows

// initialize
$this->belongsToMany('OfferRows', [
    'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER',
]);
```

Is either one correct, or is there third alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to retrieve the join table data irrespectively of whether a product exists / is linked, then you should go with something like the latter solution.

However the `Products` association in the `OfferRowsTable` class should be a `belongsTo` one, as `hasOne` expects the foreign key to exist in the target table, ie the `products` table. Using `hasOne` will at the latest break things when saving associations.

Also the `belongsToMany` association in the `ProductsTable` class should point to `Offers`, not `OfferRows`.